# How to make gnome-terminal command act like object in python

Tags: python, object, gnome-terminal

I'm trying to create a gnome-terminal windows and after that I want to write something at terminal window (echo) like a buffering screen in a while loop.

```css
import os

x = os.system("gnome-terminal -e")

while True:
    x.write("echo % s "%(buffering))
    if progress == 0:
        break
```

So, I have to open gnome-terminal window before while loop because if I don't gnome terminal opens and close at each loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a named pipe:

```
import os,time

def client():
    try:
        os.mkfifo("named_pipe")
    except OSError as e:
        print(e.message)
    named_pipe = os.open("named_pipe", os.O_WRONLY)
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
         os.write(named_pipe, 'Time {}\n'.format(time.asctime()))


def server():
    from subprocess import check_call
check_call(['gnome-terminal', '-e', "python script.py"])


pid = os.fork()
foo() if pid != 0 else bar()
```

In script.py:

```
import os
with open('named_pipe') as f:
    for line in iter(f.readline, ""):
        print(line.rstrip())
    os.unlink("named_pipe")
```

You could also use a unix domain socket or tcp.